# Fetch ASP.NET label control through JavaScript the right way?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Good day. I am trying to fetch an asp.net label control's text value using javascript. However the control id is returned as null when I use

```
var a = document.getElementById('<%= lblTreatyNo.ClientID %>').innerText;
```

However it does work when I use the full name from source like

```
var a = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTreatyNo').innerText;
```

I am using master pages in my site design. I want to know the correct way of fetching this. Isn't there a way not to use the full name from the source file?

Update here is my code sample

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTreatyNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>    
<asp:Button ID="btnNewSec" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:void(window.open ('ft_newsec.aspx?ftid='+document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTreatyNo').innerHTML+'',null,'height=220,width=300,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes')); return false;" Text="Add New Company" CausesValidation="False" Width="155px" />
```

Comment: I don't see how your second code sample is correct, did you put <%= %> around the generated client id on accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem that I can see is that you're trying to get the element before the DOM is loaded. An actual scenario would be if the `asp:Label` is defined after the JavaScript code; by the time the JavaScript code is executed, the element you're trying to get is *not known*, and `document.getElementById` will return `null`. But then again, the second approach shouldn't work neither in this case. We'd need to know more about the context to help you, i.e. the code where both the `asp:Label` and the JavaScript code are defined; it looks like something else might be wrong.

Regarding your question at the end, using the `ClientID` property is the *right* way to do it, since `ClientID` will be the value of the element's `id` attribute (HTML).

### Update, in regard to Popo's newly posted code

`lblTreatyNo.ClientID` in the `OnClientClick` property (in the ASPX source) isn't rendered; if you have a look at the source code of the rendered page, you'll see something like the following:

```
onclick="&lt;%= lblTreatyNo.ClientID %>
```

No server-side code should be put in the `OnClientClick` when defined in an ASPX page, since the property's value won't be rendered. You can imagine that `OnClientClick` will be directly replaced by the JavaScript event handler `onclick` once the page is rendered, without rendering `OnClientClick`'s value.

To circumvent this problem, you either can set the `OnClientClick` property in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnNewSec.OnClientClick="javascript:void(window.open ('ft_newsec.aspx?ftid='+document.getElementById('"+lblTreatyNo.ClientID+"').innerHTML+'',null,'height=220,width=300,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes')); 

    return false;
}
```

Or, if you want to do it on the client-side, you could do the following with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%= btnNewSec.ClientID %>").click(function(e) {
        window.open('ft_newsec.aspx?ftid=' + document.getElementById('<%= lblTreatyNo.ClientID %>').innerHTML + '', null, 'height=220,width=300,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Once the DOM is loaded, the above defined jQuery code will attach your JavaScript code to the button's `click` event; once the user hits the button, your JavaScript code will be executed.

Comment: @Popo thanks for posting some more code. I've now updated my answer, and added a workaround to your problem. Hope it solves it

Comment: Using generated ID instead of original - is bad idea

Comment: @abatishchev Damn, I forgot to replace it with `lblTreatyNo.ClientID`; it wasn't intentional. I've corrected the code. Thanks for the hint. Maybe the downvote isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Thank you Giu. I did not knew previously about the server side property values not being rendered. Your post was very informative for me =)
Can I call a function in on ClientClickEvent(openWindow();). Maybe that would work as well. Thumbs up for the help !

Comment: @Popo you're welcome; I'm glad it helped you. Sure you can; the following code does exactly what you want: http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=29453#a29453 You just have to define a JavaScript function `openWindow` and *reference* (or *call*) it from within `OnClientClick`: `OnClientClick="javascript:openWindow();return false;"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample scenario.
Suppose you have a label and a button inside a content page of a master page.
On clicking the button you want the labels text at clientside.

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="Hello World"></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me"/>
</div>
```

Add this on PageLoad Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ChangeLabelText('"
            + myLabel.ClientID + "');");
    }
}
```

This way the rendered ClientID get passed to your function.
Now access it using javascript.

```
function ChangeLabelText(label_id) {
    alert(document.getElementById(label_id));
    //prevents postback, return true if you need postback
    return false;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of ASP.NET you're running? If it's 4.0 using [Control.ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) might help

Answer (score -2):

You may remove the asp short tags:

From:

```
var a= document.getElementById('<%=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTreatyNo %>').innerText;
```

To:

```
var a= document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTreatyNo').innerText;
```